# One Step Checkout Magento Problems with the theme

Tags: magento

I trying to install the one step checkout in my magento store, i have the license, but i dont have more support from them

I got this message
One Step Checkout Pro: Missing layout file or template folder of this module. Please follow the install instruction at here or you can submit a ticket at here

i follow the steps, tried to add the files in different folders and i still having the same message

Any Suggestion please?

Step 1: Go to folder by path: app/design/frontend/default/default (or by path: app/design/frontend/enterprise/default if you are using magento EE), you will see the folders (/layout, /template) then upload these folders directly into your theme by path: app/design/frontend/your _package/your_theme
Step 2: Go to folder by path: skin/frontend/default/default (or by path: skin/frontend/enterprise/default if you are using magento EE), after that upload the folder ‘mw_onestepcheckout’ into your theme by path: skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/emphasis/mw_onestepcheckout


/public_html/skin/frontend/emphasis/default/mw_onestepcheckout

`/public_html/skin/frontend/emphasis/emphasis/mw_onestepcheckout

`/public_html/skin/frontend/default/emphasis/mw_onestepcheckout
```

Answer (score 1):

// First confirm that layout file and template file present in following path.

```
1. /public_html/app/design/frontend/emphasis/default/layout/mw_onestepcheckout.xml (your module layout file)

2. /public_html/app/design/frontend/emphasis/default/template/mw_onestepcheckout/       (your module folder path)

3.Clear cache. (Admin panel login : system->cache management)
```

Comment: her theme is not called 'mw_onestepcheckout' it is 'default'. mw_onestepcheckout is the name of the module

Comment: Great, the only other thing is that in the template folder, the module may not have a folder named mw_onestepcheckout. This might cause confusion for people who are trying to install this module if they cant find this folder, and may cause them to upload the skin folder into this directory

Comment: Hi, thank you for all the comments! I did all the steps, all the files are in the right folders and i still getting some message saying i need fix something, also in the checkout page i got some errors in the layout

Answer (score 0):

Inside app/design/frontend/{{PACKAGE}}/{{THEME}}/ there are two main folders we need to look at for this, a `layout` folder and a `template` folder.

Taking into account your current package and theme, you need to follow these steps

Step 1: upload the folder 'template' into
`/public_html/app/design/frontend/emphasis/default/template/`

Step 2: upload the folder 'layout' into `/public_html/app/design/frontend/emphasis/default/layout/`

Step 3: Lastly, upload the mw_onestepcheckout folder into `/public_html/skin/frontend/emphasis/default/`
which I think you have already done correctly looking at your question

Comment: Can you send me some example file paths from this module, one from the layout folder one from the template folder and one from the skin folder. So i can check these files are uploaded correctly.